# (Meteor + React) Cannot access props from within subcomponent

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I am passing data from one component to another (MyApplicants) via my router (FlowRouter):

```
FlowRouter.route('/applicants', {
    name: 'Applicants',
    action: function () {
        var currentUser = Meteor.user();
        ReactLayout.render(App, {
            content:    <MyApplicants institutionID={Meteor.user().profile.institutionID} />,
            nav:        <Nav />,
            header:     <Header />
        });
    }
});
```

As you can see I'm passing `institutionID` to the new component via a prop in the router. I know that the `institutionID` is being passed because I can see it in the render of the MyApplicants component.

Here is the MyApplicants component:

```
MyApplicants = React.createClass({
    mixins: [ReactMeteorData],

    pagination: new Meteor.Pagination(Applicants, {
        perPage: 25,
        filters: {institution_id: this.props.institutionID },
        sort: {institution_id: 1, "last_name":1, "first_name":1}
    }),

    getMeteorData() {
        return {
            currentUser: Meteor.user(),
            applicants: this.pagination.getPage(),
            ready: this.pagination.ready()
        }
    },
    RenderApplicantRow(applicant, key) {
        return (
            <div key={key}>
                <p>[{applicant.institution_id}] {applicant.last_name}, {applicant.first_name}</p>
            </div>
        )
    },

    render : function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <section className="content">

               {this.data.applicants.map(this.RenderApplicantRow)}
                          {console.log(this.data.applicants)}

                          <DefaultBootstrapPaginator
                              pagination={this.pagination}
                              limit={6}
                              containerClass="text-center"/>

                </section>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

(FYI, I'm using [krounin:pagination](https://github.com/Kurounin/Pagination/).) The problem is that I cannot access `this.props.institutionID` inside of the pagination component. I know the value is getting passed (I can see it if I'm just testing output in the render) but can't figure out why it doesn't pass into the pagination call. And I know the pagination works because I do not get an error if I hard code in a value.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple scope problem I think, you need to bind it to the right context
Try something like this:

```
 pagination: function() {
     var self= this;
     new Meteor.Pagination(Applicants, {
        perPage: 25,
        filters: {institution_id: self.props.institutionID },
        sort: {institution_id: 1, "last_name":1, "first_name":1}
    })
}
```

,

Comment: Thanks. When I use that for the pagination function it looks like pagination looses its value. I get the following errors: 

    Error: this.pagination.getPage is not a function
    TypeError: this.pagination.getPage is not a function

I've also tried to return the new Meteor ... function with no success.